# adjust second div height

Tags: html, css, height

I have two divs inside a parent div.

both divs will occupy complete width of its parent.

first div has fixed height and I don't want to give height for second div, it should automatically occupy remaining height of the parent[I want to do this in css only].

below is jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/x3ebK/3/

here is the html code:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="col1">content</div>
    <div id="col2">content</div>
</div>
```

I need help in this.

I have updated the js fiddle below in below, I want "col2" to occupy remaining height of content div

[http://jsfiddle.net/x3ebK/32/](http://jsfiddle.net/x3ebK/31/)

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to use `display:table` rather than `float` like this:

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/x3ebK/28/

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div>
    <div id="col1">content</div>
    <div id="col2">content<br /><br /><br />content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
    display:table;
}
#content > div{
    display:table-row;
}
#col1 {
   width: 30%;
   background:#ff0000;
   display:table-cell;
}
#col2 {
    width: 70%;    
    background:#000fff;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

You might want to read this article :
http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/x3ebK/24/)

CSS

```
html,body { height: 100%; }

#content {
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
}

#col1 {
    width: 30%;
    background:#ff0000;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
}

#col2 {
    width: 70%;    
    float:right;
    background:#000fff;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving answer                                             No, actually I want to auto adjust height of second div.

Comment: Here the second div does "automatically occupy remaining height of the parent"...

Answer (score 0):

Try applying:

`position: absolute;` and `height: 100%;` to **#col1**

and

`height: 100%;` to **#col2**

Here is the updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/nqYAp/

Answer (score -1):

Try This
`#container{
  height:100%}
#col2
{
  height:inherit
}`